# Bootstrap elemnts gets eaten by each other

Tags: html, css, grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwYNT.png)i need your help for my bootstrap website. I struggling around to get it working but always got this annoying grid issue? I dont know exactly what it is. The Output eats some of my colores boxes if i lower the size of the screen. (using Firefox, Bootstrap)

```css
.row {

  width:100%;
  height:15rem;
  background-color: green;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top: 3%;


}

.container{
width: 100%;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

.col-md-4{
  position: relative;

  padding:5px;
  height:100%;
}

.col-md-12{
  height:100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <h1>Hello World!</h1>

 <div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
     <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:lightyellow;">
       <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
     <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:darkred;">
       <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:blue;">
     <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:lightblue;">
       <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
     </div>
   </div>

 </div>

 <div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:purple;">
     <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:red;">
       <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:pink;">
     <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:yellow;">
       <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:lightblue;">
     <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:blue;">
       <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
     </div>
   </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the picture below the 2end and 3rd items are hidden under the next row. What i'm doing wrong? The should line up under each otherafter i lower the display size. There should be 6 boxes inside but it only displays 4 of them.[Full view should looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78SsZ.png)
[elemts got eaten by each other why?Small view for smartpone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2qze.png)

behind the red box is some other hidding. I tried alot and failed so hard. Maybe someone can help me.

[left and right white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPdk6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height on the row is causing your problems. You could move the height to be on the columns instead (or remove it entirely if you don't need them to be expanded like that).

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.col-md-4 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 15rem;
}

.col-md-12 {
  height: 15rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:lightyellow;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:darkred;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:blue;">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:lightblue;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:purple;">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:red;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:pink;">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:lightblue;">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:blue;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man you saved me houers or even days to figure out what is wrong. 1 more question if its fine? How to change the size of the container to be with 90% of the full page? I found something called @Container but dont know how to use it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. I see your `.container` class has `width: 100%` set on it. Are you just wanting that to be 90%?

Comment: As you can see in the added picture above there is a white space on the left side and on the right side of the boxes. How to reduce this whitespace so that the boxes have a higher width. Maybe 90% of the full page width. Soory for my late response.

Comment: `.container` is a bootstrap class with a set width. So rename your class to something else and use that instead.